# Pritunl startup - error

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to build pritunl vpn server from source. I build using setup.py build and install. When installing setup.py install i got an error. When I try to start pritunl server the following error arise.

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in bootstrap_inner
>   self.run() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
>   self.target(self.**args, *self.kwargs) File
>   "/home/next/virtual_env/venvvpn/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl-1.27.1282.77-py2.7.egg/pritunl/setup/server.py",
>   line 218, in server_thread 'KEY_PATH': server_key_path or '', File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in init** errread,
>   errwrite) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in
>   _execute_child raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory